# Identifying Hamiltonian Systems with Phase Portrait

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hamiltonian-path

the following is a homework question (that isn't going to be graded) and I'm not sure how to do it.

[image]

I know that the solution trajectories cannot cross the H(x,y)=constant curves, but I'm not sure how to identify where the H(x,y)=constant curves are in the phase plane.

Comment: Just kidding I figured it out.  A Hamiltonian system never has a sink or source equilibrium point, which means that (a) and (c) cannot be Hamiltonian.  Boom.